# MySQL: Complete missing data with parent tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Let's assume I have three tables in my database, representing a hierarchic order:

`countries`, `states`, and `cities`

Each city is connected to one state, each state to one country. This is simple to represent in a database.

Let's further assume each of those tables contains a field `tax_rate`. In a basic case the tax rate is defined on country level and `null` on all other levels. However, it could be overwritten on any of the levels below.

When I query for a city node I would like to get its tax rate. It could be defined right within the same node, but more likely it will be defined on any of the next-higher levels.

**What is the most efficient way to accomplish this either in MySQL or on PHP level?** In my real life application there will not be only one such field but many of them.

Below is a simple database schema of my example. Of course it would also have foreign key definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tax_rate` float(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `tax_rate`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,8.00,'Switzerland'),
    (2,16.00,'Germany');


CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_rate` float(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

NSERT INTO `cities` (`id`, `state_id`, `tax_rate`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,1,NULL,'Bern'),
    (2,1,NULL,'Zollikofen'),
    (3,2,NULL,'Zurich'),
    (4,2,5.30,'Wettingen'),
    (5,2,NULL,'Winterthur'),
    (6,2,6.60,'Handligen'),
    (7,3,NULL,'Bayern-Town 1'),
    (8,3,NULL,'Bayern-Town 2'),
    (9,3,9.00,'Bayern-Town 3');


CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_rate` float(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `states` (`id`, `country_id`, `tax_rate`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,1,NULL,'Bern'),
    (2,1,9.00,'Zurich'),
    (3,2,NULL,'Bavaria');
```

Comment: may be you could join the tables and select the column from right table using mysql IF statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be handled on either level: MySQL or PHP

I'd prefer the MySQL approach:

```
select cities.name, COALESCE(cities.tax_rate,states.tax_rate,countries.tax_rate) from cities
join states on cities.state_id=states.id
join countries on states.country_id = countries.id
```

This will return the city's tax rate if it is not NULL, else the state's. If that also is null, it'll return the country's tax rate.

Answer (score 2):

Use COALESCE(). That's what it's for.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about COALESCE().